# Send JNI C stderr/stdout through log4j

Tags: java, logging, java-native-interface

My java app uses JNI to invoke a library written in C. This native library logs errors to stderr but I would like to redirect the error stream through my log4j logger somehow. Is this possible?

The C library is external - I don't have the source, so cannot change it.

Thanks

Comment: Is the JNI layer part of your application or part of the external toolkit?

Comment: That's part of the external toolkit too.

Comment: With what granularity do you call the external code and how much data is passed back and forth?  In other words, could you spawn the work as a child process?  Redirecting stdout or stderr of C code that you don't control is very difficult.  I thought I'd done it before but it's been at least 10 years since I wrote that kind of C code and all I can find online is about redirecting it to a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I have not tried this answer; YMMV.

The POSIX method `freopen` will change the underlying file associated with a stream. As the manpage states: "The primary use of the freopen() function is to change the file associated with a standard  text  stream (stderr, stdin, or stdout)".

So, you could create your own JNI library that simply redirects the stream into a file. **However**, there are several serious roadblocks to making this work:

1. You'll need to ensure that your Java
   program doesn't itself use standard
   streams, because they'll be
   redirected too. A workaround for
   this is to change `System.out` et al
   to something else when your program starts up.
2. It's possible that
   the third-party library bypasses the standard
   text streams, and writes directly to
   the underlying file descriptor. It's
   unlikely but possible. I can't
   remember whether freopen() just
   changes the file descriptor used by
   the buffered stream, or actually
   re-opens the underlying fd.
3. You'll
   still have the problem of connecting
   changes to the "file" to a logger.

That last point is by far the biggest: stdio writes to an OS-level file descriptor. You would have to create some Java-level code to read that descriptor and write to a log. My first thought is that you'd have to use a named pipe, and then spin up a new Java thread to read that pipe. But that won't be portable to different operating systems, and will that you manage the pipe name in your program's configuration.

Assuming that this is a server program, and does not itself process the standard IO streams, I think your best solution will be to configure Log4J with a console logger, and simply redirect all console output to a file.

Or talk to the people who wrote the library, to get them to add configurable logging.

Answer (score -1):

My C is a little rusty, but it may be possible, since you can invoke the PrinStream methods from within a C via JNI. But you'll have to find a way to hook into when the stream gets written to.

Update: This might help you with hooking into stdout from within C:

http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Hook-Functions.html

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't change the C library as it's not mine.