# stdout in Applet Java console

Tags: java, windows, applet, console, stdout

My signed Java applet loads a native DLL. The DLL prints traces to stdout. When I run the applet under Eclipse I see these traces in Eclipse console. But I don't see them in Java console when I run it as an applet in a web-browser. Is it possible at all?

```
<applet name="name" id="game" archive="my.jar" code="path/to/main.class" mayscript="" title="Java"> 
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true"> 
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx384m -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -XX:CompileThreshold=1500 -Xincgc -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xss6m"> 
    <div class="nojava"> 
        <h1> 
            Please Update Java</h1> 
    </div> 
</applet>
```

Windows, preferably Firefox if it matters

Comment: Although a trusted applet can redirect `System.out` & `System.err`, by ***default*** they go to the console.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: `System.out/System.err` really do, and that's fine and I don't want to change this. But `stdout` from native DLL doesn't, and I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I thought `stdout` would map to `System.out`.

Comment: related but different question: [Send JNI C stderr/stdout through log4j](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982927/send-jni-c-stderr-stdout-through-log4j?rq=1)

Comment: If source is available, can you change your DLL to use stderr instead?

Answer (score 3):

The `stdout` of DLLs usually goes to the `stdout` of the browser, at least in my experience. So if all you want is have a look at those messages, then I suggest you start your browser from the command line (at least on Linux) and have a look at what gets printed there. Not sure how this would be done on Windows.

Redirecting the `stdout` for the DLL would be asking for trouble: multiple applets from multiple pages can be executed by the same plugin process, and as C I/O streams are per-process, redirecting them for one applet would redirect them for all. It probably can be done (using a pipe and `dup2` on the native side), but you should only follow that route if the applet gets executed in a very controlled environment, where you can rule out bad interaction with other applets.

The proper solution, of course, is having the DLL not print to stdout, but use some callback instead. If you have access to the source code of the DLL, that's the solution I'd prefer. If not, perhaps you can talk to the authors of the DLL. On some platform (I know about Linux), you might be able to get similar effects by intercepting and modifying certain library calls using an interposer library, but that's anything but portable. On the other hand, a native DLL isn't too portable either, so this might work for you.

Comment: tried Firefox console (firefox.exe -console) on Windows. DLL output doesn't appear there

Comment: stderr is there for when you don't want to override stdout and it always defaults to the terminal...