# How to disable native library output?

Tags: java, io, output, jna

I'm using a native DLL library with JNA.
This library outputs (via `printf` or `cout` I suppose) some stuff in my java console that I don't want to see.
The library is provided by someone else and I can't modify it.

My java application also print some stuff in the console (with a logger), that I want to see there.

Is there a way to disable the native library output, or even better to route this output to a file ?

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935474/ndk-how-to-remove-log-debug-statements-on-release)?

Comment: Since you are using a logger try to redirect stdout and stderr to the logger (or a logger) as well. Then you should be able to redirect or suppress it. How exactly this is done depends on the actual logging framework you use. (Something like that might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982927/send-jni-c-stderr-stdout-through-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your own library or library provided by someone else? If you are the owner of the library, then this might help.
[How to disable cout output in the runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30184998/how-to-disable-cout-output-in-the-runtime)

Comment: The library is provided by someone else and I can not modify it !